# How to change color of tabs in MDTabBarViewController?

Tags: ios, material-design

I am usig this library https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS/ in my iOS app. Specifically I am using the MDTabBarController and I need a way to change the tabs colors so they match my brand identity. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply reference your tabBar like this:

```
[[_tabBarViewController tabBar] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabbar.tabBar.indicatorColor = UIColor.red
tabbar.tabBar.textColor = UIColor.red
tabbar.tabBar.normalTextColor = UIColor.white
```